# HTTrack wait until page search completed

Tags: http, download, web, httrack

I'm trying to download with HTTrack the results of a search request at the URL here

Unfortunately the download starts immediately and doesn't get the search result (as the page is still showing a wheel).

Question: is it possible to force a pause after the first page request or, alternatively, to define a check (for instance a keyword search on the page) before it starts?

Worst case: is there any other website copier that would be able to do this?

Many thanks, Tom